# Android 5 feature - customizing shadow on edge of the screen when swiping

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

What is the technical name for the shadow that shows on the bottom of the screen in the screenshot? I can't seem to find a term for it through online searches.

In case anyone reads this who does not yet have Android 5, but is somewhat familiar with its features, this shadow appears when you try to swipe in a direction when there is nowhere left to go (e.g. Swiping down when already at the bottom of this menu).

Is it possible to change the color of this shadow in my own app? - and if so, how?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Edge effect: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EdgeEffect.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/EdgeEffectCompat.html and could also be helpful: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off Brian's comment, I believe one way to change the color of the edge effect is through `colorPrimary`, which the [developer guides](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html) describe as:

`The primary branding color for the app; used as the action bar background, recents task title and in edge effects.`

Changing `colorPrimary` and other attributes while using the `Material` theme, found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html).

Also, see `colorEdgeEffect`:

`Further attributes give fine grained control over colorizing controls, see: colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated, colorControlHighlight, colorButtonNormal, colorSwitchThumbNormal, colorEdgeEffect, statusBarColor and navigationBarColor.`

```
<resources>
  <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <!--   changing colorPrimary will change the color of the edge effect -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```